# iOS how to make a menu controller which can come in and out

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a button in my app which is always on the very top of the window and, when clicked, it brings up a menu (which contains navigation buttons). Currently, I have the button create a new instance of the menu controller every time it is clicked and it calls

```
topmost_controller.present(MenuController())
```

When the menu controller is clicked out of, `dismiss` is called on itself. However, I don't see the need of creating a new instance each time, as the controller is static. When I try to write

```
static let controller = MenuController()
```

inside the `MenuController` class, and replace the previous method of presenting with

```
topmost_controller.present(MenuController.controller)
```

I get the error `Application tried to present modally an active controller` after clicking the presentation button more than once. How can I achieve using a static instance of `MenuController`? Should I even care? Note: I'm not using storyboards. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest (and coolest) way you can make a menu is by using this pod that I recently discovered 
https://github.com/yannickl/FlowingMenu

```
pod 'FlowingMenu'
```

it provides an interactive transition manager to display menu with a flowing and bouncing effects.

this is a pic that shows you how it works
https://camo.githubusercontent.com/59f8644f915299e0e80c09948d3db8efd8c9beae/687474703a2f2f79616e6e69636b6c6f72696f742e636f6d2f7265736f75726365732f666c6f77696e676d656e752e676966

(if you have troubles using it comment your problems here, personally it took me a bit to understand it hahaha)

(If you don't know how to use CocoaPods this is a tutorial that can help you https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#toc_3)